# Problem extracting values from mysql Python

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I get an error when I'm trying to convert a field from a mysql query into a variable, my code it's like:

```
 def GetCompanyswithNoResult():
 global tabla_db
 connection = mysql.connector.connect
 mycursor = connection.cursor()

 sql = "SELECT * FROM "+ tabla_db +" WHERE RESULT = 0"

 mycursor.execute(sql)

 myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

 ID = myresult[0]
 Location = myresult[2]
 Market = myresult[3] + " into " + myresult[4]

 return [ID, Location, Market]

ID, League, Match = GetMatcheswithNoResult()
```

the error message that return it's:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File, line 248, in 
>       ID, League, Match = GetCompanywithNoResult()
>     File , line 123, in GetCompanywithNoResult
>       ID = myresult[0]
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I need some help...

How can I export these values without error?

Comment: I think either your result is None or you can fetch data from myresult like dictionary as `location = myresult['location']`

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal thanks a lot, this solution works for me!